# What's the best way to handle similar applications with almost identical core functions?

Tags: android

So I am developing one application on Android with multiple features. Now I am tasked to replicate this same app in different styles for different customers. When I say style, this may include totally different layout style, graphic, color, language, basically every part of UI maybe different.

However, core function like server connection, data object, payment gateway, etc. Are very similar in every application. The problem is that, all of this application will need to be maintain and develop further. Most of them will be going in the same direction.

What's the best way for me to handle situation like this? I tried to split common methods into Utilities classes for easy plug in the next projects but UI-related stuff like Map and else isn't really easy to separate.

Is there a way to create patch-like function that allow me to unified one core application and slapping different UIs on others? Or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a library, you can create an android library project, take a look at this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html

Comment: I realized that option but thanks for reaffirming here again. Is it possible to have a running application as library?

Comment: Not really, you can convert your application into a library but then you won't be able to run that as an application.